# MinGW parallel make: CreateProcess error

Tags: mingw, gnu-make

I am using MinGW under Windows 10 for my development tools. I have a C project with ~100 source files. I created a makefile to build the project, and it worked fine, every time.

But then I tried to speed up the build by passing `-j4` to `mingw32-make`, telling it to use four processors in parallel. This did indeed speed up the build, but only for a while: after a seemingly random number of compilations (the number changes every time), I get the error

> gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I also get this error with `-j2`, but it seems to be less common.

`mingw32-make --version` reports

> GNU Make 4.1
>   Built for i686-w64-mingw32

I also have a large C++ project under Qt Creator, and this exhibits exactly the same problem.

Any ideas what could be causing this random CreateProcess error?

Here is an example of a failing `CreateProcess` call:

```
CreateProcess(C:\Users\TonyK\AppData\Local\Temp\make44344-14.bat,C:\Users\TonyK\AppData\Local\Temp\make44344-14.bat,...)
```

Comment: M$ offers an [application verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20028) which seems to catch misbehaving applications, in particular calls to CreateProcess with unclean parameters. Maybe you could give it a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450556/mingw-make-throwing-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error . Cannot flag it as such while there's a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what the problem was: BullGuard. This anti-virus program is the most officious that I have come across, and is completely impractical for a serious developer. More than once it has refused to run programs that I have compiled myself. The last straw was when it interrupted my QtCreator development environment because of some 'questionable' operation it was performing (I don't know -- spawning a sub-process or something), and I lost four of my source files! Luckily I had a same-day backup, so it only cost me a couple of hours' work.

So I uninstalled BullGuard.

And now my parallel make runs like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

Can be a race condition i.e. lack of synchronization between some interdependent build steps.

Use `--trace` argument for GNU make to see what it's trying and `--output-sync` to group all output for a particular recipe and target together. The goal is to see which command line is producing the error and for which file.

---

Other possible reasons:

@Vroomfondel suspects this is a bug in `mingw32-make`. This can only apply if the temporary `.bat` files are created as part of internal `mingw32-make` logic rather than `Makefile` logic. Here, you need to debug trace the time of `CreateProcess` calls vs the creation of relevant files.

Another possible reason is [registry settings related to `cmd.exe` or `.bat` extension broken by malware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450556/mingw-make-throwing-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error). If this is the case, the error occurs when carrying out `CreateProcess` and is external to `mingw32-make`.