# How to prevent make from deleting it's own temporary batch files

Tags: makefile

make running under Windows sometimes shells out some commands
(see [What causes GNU Make to shell out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506418/what-causes-gnu-make-to-shell-out))
into batch files in a temp folder. Here's an example:

Makefile:

```
hello.new: hello.old
    copy /y hello.old hello.new
```

Output for make -d:

```
[...]
Prerequisite `hello.old' is newer than target `hello.new'.
Must remake target `hello.new'.
Creating temporary batch file C:\users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\make208562.bat
CreateProcess(C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\make208562.bat,C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\make208562.bat,...)
Putting child 0x00e0ec28 (hello.new) PID 14719728 on the chain.
Live child 0x00e0ec28 (hello.new) PID 14719728
        1 file(s) copied.
Reaping winning child 0x00e0ec28 PID 14719728
Cleaning up temp batch file C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\make208562.bat
Removing child 0x00e0ec28 PID 14719728 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `hello.new'.
[...]
```

After execution, make deletes these batch files.
But for debugging purposes I'd need to look into them.

I browsed the make documentation but without success.
And the only similar web hit I could find is the above one.

So does anybody know how to prevent make from deleting these temp batch files?
(Possibly except of changing the source and recompiling make...)

Comment: Can you explain why you need to see the content of the batch file? It seems like an implementation detail to me that should be of no interest to a user. It probably just contains the `copy` command.

Comment: Yes, in the given example it is ovious what would be in the file.
But in the real and much more complex case, we get an error
in one of the tools called by make. But we don't now the sequence of the calls before this, With -d we see that a lot of actions happen and so a lot of batch files are generated. But without the content it is difficult to see what really happens.
Of course it would be better if the makefile would be designed in a way that it is clear for every reader what happens after what...

Comment: Perhaps you can put a `pause` command at the end of the recipe. This will give you time to inspect the temporary batch file. You might need to force make to run all commands in a single shell (use `&&` to combine commands or use `.ONESHELL`).

Comment: The content of the batch file is exactly what make printed to the screen as the command it will run.  However to answer your question directly: there is no way that I'm aware of to prevent make from deleting those files once the command has completed.  Of course, since make is free software you can always edit the code to prevent the delete operation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try both, pause and .oneshell tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, tried both:
"pause" worked, doesn't help in my case and needs to be written at any line.
".ONESHELL" didn't work for me.

Our "make" is part of toolchain from HighTec gcc collection so I'll try to get more help from them.
Thank you all for contributing.